# Crossrider IE encoding with JSONP

Tags: internet-explorer, encoding, character-encoding, crossrider

working in extension that appears popup when user double click in any word in the page

it's working fine in FF and GC but it appears character encoding problem in IE

[image: IE Encoding vs Firefox Encoding]

i'm using JSONP

```
function PopupGenerate(e,selectedText){
  PopUpMessage(selectedText,waitMessage);
  appAPI.request.get({
  url: WebServiceUrl + encodeURIComponent(selectedText),      
  onSuccess: function(responseString) {
    var response = JSON.parse(responseString);
    if(response.SearchResults == "NoResult")
        {           
             PopUpMessage(selectedText,noResultMessage);
        }
        else
        {   
            PopUpWord(selectedText,response,e);
        }
  },
  onFailure: function(httpCode) {
  PopUpMessage(selectedText,ConnectionErrorMessage);
  },
contentType: 'application/json'
});    
}
```

so how to fix it in IE?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with encoded strings in Internet Explorer. You can workaround the issue by sending the text using HTML special characters that you can encode using one of the online encoders:

- http://www.unicodetools.com/unicode/convert-to-html.php
- http://web.forret.com/tools/html.asp

[**Disclosure**: I am a Crossrider employee]